# How to use array elements as labels using for loop in Template Django?

Tags: django, templates, for-loop, label, formset

I have the following template code,presently i m getting for loop counter as label for my formset. How can i get elements of array 'month' (eg  month.counter, where counter is loop) as my label?? I tried {{month.forloop.counter}} but that didnt worked

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Actuals</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>Actuals Data</h1>

<h2>Your Account Number is : {{ Account_Number }}</h2>
<h2>You Chose {{ Year }} {{month}} as period.</h2>


{% if form.errors %}

    <p style="color: red;">
   Please correct the error{{ form.errors|pluralize }}below.</p>

   {% endif %}


<form action="." >
    {{ formset.management_form }}




<table>

      {% for form in formset %}

    {{form.id}}

            <div class="field">
                {{ form.Value.errors }}
                <label for="id_Value">{{months}}.{{forloop.counter}}</label>
                {{ form.Value }}
            </div>


      {% endfor %}

    </table>



</form>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using custom templatetags. Sample code is given below:

add following to /{app_name}/templatetags/app_tags.py

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def month(value, counter):
    try:
        month = value[counter]
    except IndexError:
        month = ""
    return month
```

put following in your template

```
{% load app_tags %}

............
............

{% for form in formset %}
    {{form.id}}
    <div class="field">
        {{ form.Value.errors }}
        <label for="id_Value">{{ months|counter:forloop.counter }}</label>
        {{ form.Value }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}

............
............
```

[View this link](http://copilotco.com/mail-archives/django.2009/msg00904.html), some person has also tried different methods to do this; although none of them worked. ;)

Comment: thanks for ur help...jst that there ws a small error in ur code,in the template it should be `<label for="id_Value">{{ months|month:forloop.counter0 }}</label>`

Answer (score 0):

There isn't ready-made filter/tag for this in django template.
You could try writing your custom filter/tag. Refer [Custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/)